# Permission to write sacred names on fruit?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, food, names

Most of the times, I observe sacred names like (*Allah and Muhammad SAWW*) are written on fruits, vegetables, snow and many more things. e.g.

[image]

**What does Islam says about this practice?**

Doesn't it bring any discomfort to the religion, while the fruit/vegetable will finally be thrown away!

Comment: When you write sacred names on food items you need to make sure that you eat this item as wasting food only for the sake of decoration is haram. You cut the fruit/veg/cake in smaller pieces, so the name is not recognisable any more and you eat ist with your guests. Another question is, is it good to spend a lot of time shaping this watermelon when it will be destroyed by eating in a few hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Noor. Submit an answer with references, so it shall be official answer.